# Dividir bigdecimal java

Tags: java, sql-server

Hola tengo las siguientes líneas de código.

validateData = new BigDecimal(vcAdditional02.replace(",", "").trim());
validateData.divide(100);

Esto es porque quiero dividir el valor que está asignado en la variable validateData, la cual en la primer línea convierto a big decimal, cabe recalcar que estoy trabajando en una base de datos, sin embargo al ejecutar el código, me sale el error method .divide no found in java class big decimal alguien sabra porque o de qué manera puedo dividir mi valor entre 100 ://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [java.math.BigDecimal .divide (divisor BigDecimal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)) se utiliza para calcular el cociente de dos BigDecimals. El cociente viene dado por (este / divisor) . Este método realiza una operación sobre el BigDecimal actual mediante el cual se llama a este método y el BigDecimal se pasa como parámetro.

```
BigDecimal number=new BigDecimal(100);
validateData.divide(number);
```

Comment: Entiendo....o intentaré de está manera ://

Comment: Muchas gracias bro si me funciono me has salvado :3